# vectorize nested loops with lapply

Tags: r, vectorization, graph-theory

I am trying to vectorize the topological sort for a faster run
Part of it is a `while` with a nested `for`. I am having trouble with the vectorizing . 
The idea of thisfunction is tosort interdependent tasks

This is the code I have so far:

```
tsort <- function(deps) {
  nm <- names(deps)
  libs <- union(as.vector(unlist(deps)), nm)
  s <- c()
  s <- unlist(lapply(libs,function(x){
    if(!(x %in% nm)) {
      s <- c(s, x)
    }
  }))
  k <- 1
  while(k > 0) {
    k <- 0
    for(x in setdiff(nm, s)) {
      r <- c(s, x)
      if(length(setdiff(deps[[x]], r)) == 0) {
        s <- r
        k <- 1
      }
    }
  }
  if(length(s) < length(libs)) {
    v <- setdiff(libs, s)
    stop(sprintf("Unorderable items :\n%s", paste("", v, sep="", collapse="\n")))
  }
  s
}
```

here is a list of interdependent tasks that can be sorted with the function:

```
tasks <- list(
"seven" = c("eight", "nine", "ten", "seven", "five", "one", "eleven", "two"),
"one" = c("two", "one", "three", "four"),
"five" = c("two", "five", "three"),
"six" = c("eight", "nine", "three", "six", "five", "one", "two", "four"),
"twelve" = c("twelve", "two", "one", "three", "four"),
"thirteen" = c("thirteen", "two", "three"),
"fourteen" = c("fourteen", "two", "three"),
"fifteen" = c("two", "three"),
"three" = c("two", "three"),
"four" = c("two", "four"),
"eleven" = c("eight", "two"),
"ten" = c("two", "ten"),
"nine" = c())
```

The part i am trying to vectorize is:

```
k <- 1
while(k > 0) {
  k <- 0
  for(x in setdiff(nm, s)) {
    r <- c(s, x)
    if(length(setdiff(deps[[x]], r)) == 0) {
      s <- r
      k <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

I am  finding it dificult to vectorize the main part of the function where i have a `for` and a `while` together

Comment: I'm noticing syntax errors in your code. What problems are you having?

Comment: Vectorising iterative processes is a something that you'll get better at over time. It requires a different type of thinking than you're probably used to when programming, and it will seem foreign at first.

It's hard to read your code without proper indentation, but my recommendation is always start at the deepest level, and move outwards. Also, check for values, vectors, or matrices that may be pre-computed to decrease clutter and simplify reasoning about the vectorised processes.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do with this code?

Comment: @RichardScriven it ran okso i dont thinkthere are any syntax errors

Comment: @josilber this sunction it to sort interdependent tasks it is a code for topological sorting like unix's tsort

Comment: There's multiple issues with your code, like growing objects etc. Please provide us with some test data and the wanted outcome so we can test possible solutions and benchmark them.

Comment: @JorisMeys i added a list that can be tested for the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take a look at the package `igraph` that has a function `topological.sort()` for this. It provides a lot more functionality to work with graphs, and every problem where topological sort is needed, can normally be reformulated in terms of graphs.

I'm not completely sure your code does correct sorting. You have two levels of looping: The inner loop goes over all x that are in nm but not in s. The outer loop is a while loop, and starts that process again.

With every pass through the inner loop, you take the result of previous passes into account. This leads to a funny result: whereas "thirteen", "forteen" and "fifteen" don't contain a connection to "five" or "one" and "six" does, "six" is still sorted topologically before either of the other. That's because "six" is added after "one" and "five", but in the same loop.

This behaviour -if correct- cannot be vectorized in any way. However, as far as I understand it, "thirteen", "forteen" and "fifteen" should be sorted before and not after "six".

This said, you have a very easy vectorization above the part you're interested in:

```
   s <- unlist(lapply(libs,function(x){
     if(!(x %in% nm)) {
       s <- c(s, x)
     }
  }))
```

is actually nothing else but `s <- setdiff(libs,nm)`. Plus, the assignment you do there doesn't make sense, as the `s` from `s <- c(s,x)` is created in the local environment of `lapply` and has no effect whatsoever on the outer `s`. All it does, is exactly the same as `invisible(x)`.

If you want to vectorize in such a way that you do the following :

- loop over all names not in the solution yet, and check if their sets cover everything in the solution
- add the names for which this is TRUE to the solution
- repeat until all names are in the solution

you can use the code below. Notice how I pre-allocate memory space to hold the solution. This preallocation saves quite a bit in memory operations. Growing objects in R, like you do in your code, is wasting resources.

Also note that my code will give a different ordering from your code, for the reason explained above.

```
tsort2 <- function(deps) {
  nm <- names(deps)
  libs <- union(as.vector(unlist(deps)), nm)
  s <- setdiff(libs,nm) 

  #Preallocation
  out <- vector(mode(libs),length(libs))
  out[seq_along(s)] <- s

  x <- setdiff(nm,s)
  lpos <- length(s)

  # go over all x and check which ones contain all names in the 
  # current solution.
  # Add these names to the solution
  # remove these names from x
  # repeat until x is empty
  while(length(x) > 0){
    tmp <- out[seq_len(lpos)]
    id <- sapply(x, function(i){
       length(setdiff(deps[[i]],c(i,tmp))) == 0
    } )
    id <- which(id)
    lid <- length(id)
    idout <- seq(lpos+1,length.out=lid)
    out[idout] <- x[id]
    x <- x[-id]
    lpos <- lpos + lid
  }

  if(length(out) < length(libs)) {
    v <- setdiff(libs, out)
    stop(sprintf("Unorderable items :\n%s", paste("", v, sep="", collapse="\n")))
  }
  out
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million i have another theoretical question - can i parallelize the sapply part?

Comment: actually there is something wrong with this code it does not the length of `out` will always be the same as libs sowe need to add something like out[out!=""] to the if statement

Comment: @eliavs This is just a "proof of concept" answer, obviously you need to tailor it to your needs. the `sapply` part can easily be parallelized using eg the `parallel` package in R. When doing this, keep in mind it pays of more to split a list into a few sublists and loop over those. That will keep the overhead of the parallelization low.